# No early serial console on a system that needs a kernel module loaded for the UART

Tags: systemd, serial-console

I have a Board which uses a High-speed UART instead of some legacy hardware thats compiled into the kernel. The serial device only gets detected after loading the kernel module `intel_lpss_pci`.
I am on debian "buster" which uses systemd to manage everything-

This means that enabling output and a getty login is not working as expected.

- `console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty0` will not cause systemd to open a getty login
- kernel messages are delayed as well (and incomplete)
- systemd will open the getty prompt if I manually add the target
- That target does not work for rescue mode
- That target does nothing for the init-ramdisk

**Workaround for the normal System**

I found that manually telling systemd to open a login via getty works: `systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service`
This still adds some notable delay to displaying the first kernel messages, but I can atleast login.

**Adding the module to initramfs (did not help)**
I added the intel_lpss_pci module to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`, rebuilt the init-ramfs and verified the module was copied there.
This did not make a difference

**Required behaviour**
I want the serial console to work (as I don't have a screen), straight from the Ramdisk - *without recompiling a kernel*.
Is there anyone knowledgeable what I am missing?
Do I need to add a script to init-ramfs to load this module as early as possible, and if so - how does this work with the initramfs-tools?

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248287/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278842/ , and tangentially https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194197/ .

Comment: nope, the dependency on kernel modules to make the tty's appear late seem to be the additional trouble that's not handled in any of these